# Safari 4 - AdBlock Plus

Tags: browser-addons, safari

Unfortunately I can't use AdBlock Plus for Safari, so what' do you use to block ads assuming you're using Safari?

Comment: I think you mean "AdBlock", not "AdBlock Plus".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use (or are willing to) Safari 5, [SafariAdblock](http://safariadblock.com/) (a port of the Chrome extension, not the plugin that was used with Safari 4) works quite well.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention whether or not you're running under Windows or Mac.  I'll assume Mac, and if that's the case, have a look at [Safari Adblocker](http://www.sweetpproductions.com/safariadblocker/), which seems to work pretty well.

Comment: Too bad that's for Mac users only :). Wish we also had something like that on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://opindian.com/blog/2009/02/25/adblock-solution-for-safari-4-windows-and-mac/), you will need to use a custom CSS file (like [Fanboy's Element Hider CSS](http://www.fanboy.co.nz/adblock/opera/) for Opera) to block out the ads from websites. However, it hides the ads more than it actually blocks them.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than something specifically for Safari, try an [ad-blocking hosts file](http://www.mvps.org/winhelp2002/hosts.htm) for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [K9 Web Protection](http://www1.k9webprotection.com/), which is a children's filtering software that I highly recommend...**However,** you could turn OFF all the features except for the web advertisement blocking, and that would do the job...Works on Windows and Mac, see [download page.](http://www1.k9webprotection.com/getk9/download-software.php)

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunately I can't use AdBlock Plus for Safari

[AdBlock Plus now has a Safari version.](https://adblockplus.org/en/safari) (currently in beta)